# Multiple GattCharacteristic.WriteValueAsync() results in stuttering data transmission BLE

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use WriteValueAsync() to write data without response to an BLE device.

Therefor

```
gattCharacteristic.WriteValueAsync(dataWriter.DetachBuffer(), GattWriteOption.WriteWithoutResponse))
```

is called ~200 times in ~1 seconds to write data as fast as possible.

On receiving BLE device I can see now ~2-5 write-without-response messages arriving in a "block" with nearly no time delay between them, then I see a break without new receives with a length of ~1-2 seconds before next "message-block" is received.
So data, which was written in ~1s, takes up to 90 seconds to arrive completely on BLE device (probably buffered from Windows).

Does anyone has an idea, why breaks are there and how to get rid of them?

Using a smartphone app, which does the same data transfer with write-without-response messages to same BLE device, transfers data much more quickly than Windows does.

Comment: What connection interval are you using?

Comment: Connection Interval was 60ms.
Actually it is running as it should (without breaks), but i dont know what i have changed to fix the issue.